# Didn't find class "com.example.madproject.ChapiiApplication" on path: DexPathList

Tags: kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am using the **Hilt dependency** in the project. For that we use a class which look like the following one:

```
package com.example.madproject

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class ChapiiApplication : Application(){

}
```

**When I build the project then it gives an error.
**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.madproject.ChapiiApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.madproject.ChapiiApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.madproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes6.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~42a4EQWkQ8BFYWNyJsF5jw==/com.example.madproject-SSE81BrA_UcR9xrfG6md4g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~42a4EQWkQ8BFYWNyJsF5jw==/com.example.madproject-SSE81BrA_UcR9xrfG6md4g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
```

My manifest file is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name="com.example.madproject.ChapiiApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MadProject"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginRegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

I also checked the dependencies but there is no issues.

**Here are my dependencies. For dagger hilt**

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.49")
```

**Plugins**

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
id("com.google.gms.google-services")
kotlin("kapt")
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hilt with Kotlin, use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` for `com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler` like described [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup) or [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#setup). Also you should include this to the `app/build.gradle`:

```
kapt {
 correctErrorTypes true
}
```